# Why am I getting a "Cannot return null for non-nullable field" error when doing a mutation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying my hand at (Apollo) GraphQL on the server side and have been having a probably silly issue. I'm trying to sign up a user, but keep getting the error shown in the linked image below. What is the problem? Ignore the very simple auth flow, as I'm just testing out the GraphQl

[image]

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**Schema**

```
export default `

type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
}

type Query {
    allUsers: [User]
  currentUser: User
}

type Mutation {
    createAccount(name: String!, email: String!, password: String!): User
    loginUser(email: String!, password: String!): User
    updatePassword(email: String!, password: String!, newPassword: String!): User
    deleteAccount(email: String!, password: String!): User
}

`
```

**Resolvers**

```
createAccount: async (
  parent,
  { name, email, password },
  { User },
  info
) => {
  try {
    // Check for invalid (undefined) credentials
    if (!name || !email || !password) {
      return 'Please provide valid credentials';
    }

    // Check if there is a user with the same email
    const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (foundUser) {
      return 'Email is already in use';
    }

    // If no user with email create a new user
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    await User.insert({ name, email, password: hashedPassword });

    const savedUser = await User.findOne({ email });

    return savedUser;
  } catch (error) {
    return error.message;
  }
},
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The biggest problem with your resolver is that in any number of scenarios, instead of returning a `User` object, you return a string. Your schema specifies that `createAccount` can return a `User` or `null` (if it was `User!`, it would be non-nullable and then `null` would not be a valid type either).

When you return a string in your resolver, because it's expecting an object, it coerces it into one and then starts looking for `User` properties on that object (like `name` and `email`). Those properties don't exist, and because they are non-null properties on your `User` object, returning null/undefined for them results in an error.

Your resolver should probably just throw whatever errors it needs to throw. Then they will be returned as part of the `errors` array in your response. For example:

```
// Check if there is a user with the same email
const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email })

if (foundUser) throw new Error('Email is already in use')

// If no user with email create a new user
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
await User.insert({ name, email, password: hashedPassword });

const savedUser = await User.findOne({ email });

return savedUser;
```

Now, if you have a duplicate email, the response will look something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createAccount": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Email is already in use",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createAccount"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to manipulate how your errors are shown on the client, you should utilize the `formatError` or `formatResponse` configuration options for your Apollo server middleware. It's also good practice to use custom errors, allowing you to add custom properties like `code` to more easily identify the error type on the client side.

Lastly, it's unnecessary to check if name, email or password are defined inside your resolver -- your schema already has these inputs marked as non-null, which means GraphQL will automatically return an error if any of them are missing.

Comment: HI DANIEL ARE YOU SAYING HW SHOULD NOT RETURN a string?I'm facing the same problem

Comment: my cents, in my case I forgot to use return statement on the DataSource API callback. this post helped to give a look into that area of cause! Thanks.

Comment: @Jatinder, you just saved a life with that mention of return statement. It's been 30mins of head scratching.
I had this 
`resolve: (source, args, { pgApi }) => {pgApi.userInfo(source.userId)}`
instead of 
`resolve: (source, args, { pgApi }) => pgApi.userInfo(source.userId)`